# Why does $\int_{0}^1 \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{3x}}\mathrm dx$ converge?

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence

Why does $$\int_{0}^1 \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{3x}}\mathrm dx$$ converge?

Shouldn't it not converge because as we get closer to $0,$ the integrand goes to infinity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That an integrand blows up doesn't mean the integral should not converge.

When you calculate an integral for such type of function, what you're doing is combining two limiting processes. Thus, if the limit exists, we call it the integral of the function.

That would technically be why your integral converges, if it indeed does.

Your question is not any different from asking why any other limiting process converges. Well, it converges because a certain limiting value exists -- that's all there is to it. Or, what more could be said to someone asking why $1/x$ goes to $0$ at $+\infty,$ for example, than to point them to the fact that this satisfies the definitions?

Answer (score 2):

Compare $$\int_{0}^1 \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{3x}}dx$$ with $$\int_{0}^1 \sqrt{\frac{1}{3x}}dx =2/{\sqrt 3}$$

Comment: I don't think this is what's bothering OP. Think of them as asking why $$\int_0^1\sqrt{\frac{1}{3x}}\mathrm dx$$ also converges since its integrand also blows up at one of the edges of the domain of integration.

Comment: @Allawonder You have explained it well in your solution.

Answer (score 0):

$$  \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{3x}} = \sqrt{\frac{3x+1}{3x}} = 3^{-1/2}x^{-1/2}\sqrt{3x+1}  \text{.}  $$
The constant $3^{-1/2}$ does nothing interesting around $x = 0$, nor does $\sqrt{3x+1}$ (since its interesting behaviour happens at $x = -1/3$).  Consequently, this integrand behaves like $x^{-1/2}$ at $x = 0$, but the area under that curve is finite.  Swap variables:  $y = x^{-1/2}$, so $y^{-2} = x$.  So the area under the curve $y = x^{-1/2}$ is the same as the area to the right of the $y$-axis and left of the curve $x = \min\{1,y^{-2}\}$ and that area is $1 + \int_1^\infty y^{-2} \,\mathrm{d}y$, which we should recognize is a convergent improper integral.  (If you can use the integral power rule and a limit to convince yourself that $\int_1^\infty x^{-2} \,\mathrm{d}x$ exists, you have shown that a function can go to infinity somewhere but still have a finite area under its curve.)

The usual way to remember these is the $p$-test for convergence (which has a number of other names).  [Example](http://www.sosmath.com/calculus/improper/testconv/testconv.html).  For your integral, the test is:  $\int_0^a x^p \,\mathrm{d}x$ is convergent (i.e., has a finite area under the curve) if and only if $p < 1$.  This is a little more general than $\int_0^1$ because we can let the upper bound of integration be any positive number.

Comment: This is a better attempt at explaining a comparison test, but OP could still ask why $$\int_0^1 x^{-p}\mathrm dx$$ converges for positive $p$ *since the integrand blows up at one of the endpoints.* Note the italics, which seems to be their point of confusion.

Comment: @Allawonder : Which is why the previous paragraph explains at length that the area under that curve is equivalent to the area to the left of that curve, which area can be found by the integral power rule.

Comment: Sorry, I'd wanted to mention that explicitly, but of course an integral is not an area, and cannot always be interpreted as such. Hence while this explanation may be convincing to someone willing of thinking of some particular integral as an area, you'd admit that it's not generally convincing. Saying, Look at the graph, it's finite, obviously doesn't answer the question of why, even when the integrand is not defined, the integral still exists. By the way, I'm curious about the assertion that the area enclosed by $1/\sqrt x$ is finite as $x\to +0.$

Comment: @Allawonder : Well, this is exactly the argument that has been convincing to several semesters of undergraduates, so your claim that it's not generally convincing is exactly wrong.

Comment: Again, a case of misunderstanding, probably from my inability to use the English language in the way you'd expect. By generally I do not mean to everyone (that's ridiculous, by the way -- pinning the truth on opinions!). What I meant was, generally for all other integrals whose integrands become unbounded in the domain of integration, the so-called improper integrals.

Comment: Also, I did *not* say "look at the graph, it's finite".  I said: look at the graph: the area corresponding to the value of the integral is the same as this other area which you know how to calculate using the power rule.  Is there a reason you willfully choose to behave as if the first paragraph of this answer does not exist, even after it has been referenced, twice, in these comments?

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood something about your areas, but my point is simple. What OP wants to know is how a function that becomes infinite can have a  finite integral, even if such a function is a power function.

Comment: @Allawonder : I see you bouncing around among the answers telling us what the OP wants to know.  What the OP has unambiguously stated they *actually* want to know is in their Question.  If you wish to extend or alter than Question, you should do so by asking the OP for clarification.  The OP may have several aspects of confusion, so answers addressing the various aspects are more likely to address the OP's confusions than pretending that the OP only has a specific confusion.

Comment: You've been the one pretending not to know that OP has a specific issue in mind. It's clearly stated that what they want to know is how an unbounded function can have a finite integral -- transforming such into another unbounded function obviously doesn't answer their question.

Answer (score 0):

Check that 
$$I=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} dx=2 ~~~(1)$$
also converges despite the integrand blowing off at $x=0$.
Let $f(x)$ be real and finite on $[a,b]$.The integrals of the types $$I=\int_{a}^{b} \frac{f(x)~dx}{(x-a)^\alpha}~~~~(2)$$
are one type of Improper integrals which converge and have a real finite value if $\alpha<1.$ In your case $a=0$ and $\alpha=1/2$ so you get a finite value.